# Transit visa requirement for Iranian citizen at Incheon airport for transit time of less than 12 hours

Tags: transit, transit-visas, iranian-citizens, icn

Please let me know whether Iranian needs any transit visa to stay for less than 12 hours at the Incheon airport transit area ?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=ir&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&TR=icn&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by Airlines

> Visa required, **except** for Holders of onward tickets transiting
>   Seoul Incheon (ICN), for a max. transit time of
>   24 hours.

So no, you do **not** need a visa